# Why do these two programs return different output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two programs that are supposed to reverse a list of chars (strings with length 1). While the second program gives the correct output, the first one doesn't.

Here is program #1:

```
string = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'o']
y = len(string) / 2
for letter in string:
    x = string.index(letter)
    if x < y:
       string[x], string[-1-x] = string[-1-x], string[x]
```

Here is program #2:

```
string = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'o']
y = len(string) / 2
x = 0
while x < y:
    if x < y:
        string[x], string[-1-x] = string[-1-x], string[x]
    x += 1
```

My second program successfully reverses the string, but the first one returns `['o', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'h']`. I'm glad I found a solution but would prefer to use `.index()` rather than counting each loop.

Comment: `for letter in string:` and `while x<y:` did you see the discrepancy? Also the indentation is not proper

Comment: If you just want to reverse the string, why not just use `string[::-1]`?

Comment: Ẃhy bother if you can just ```s[::-1]```? And ```string``` is a reserved word BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an anti-pattern in your first program.

```
x = string.index(letter)
```

Consider when you're indexing for the 2nd or 3rd `'l'`... `x` will **always** be 2. The condition `x < y` will kick in and reverse the positions of `'e'` and the second `'l'`.

Here's some debugging:
<sub>(Notice that x is 2 at the second, third, and fourth iterations when it *should* be 2, 3, and 4 respectively.)</sub>

```
Iter 0:
letter = 'h'; x = 0; swap √; string = ['o', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'h']
#                                       ^------------------------^

Iter 1:
letter = 'e'; x = 1; swap √; string = ['o', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
#                                            ^--------------^    

Iter 2:
letter = 'l'; x = 2; swap √; string = ['o', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
#                                                 ^----^    

Iter 3:           !
letter = 'l'; x = 2; swap √; string = ['o', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']
#                                                 ^----^    

Iter 4:           !
letter = 'l'; x = 2; swap √; string = ['o', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'h']
#                                            ^--------------^    

Iter 5:
letter = 'l'; x = 5; swap X; string = ['o', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'h']
```

Pythonically, you should use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to keep track of the index:

```
y = len(string) / 2
for i, _ in enumerate(string):
    if i < y:
       string[i], string[-1-i] = string[-1-i], string[i]
```

<sup>(An underscore was substituted for `letter` following PEP8 style guides.)</sup>

Or even better:

```
string = string[::-1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I see that the variable "string" is list of strings. You can reverse it as simple as this:

```
string = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'o']
string.reverse()
string
```

This should print `['o', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'e', 'h']`